# Convert Undirected graph to directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, jgrapht

How do you convert (can we convert?) an Undirected graph into a Directed graph.
I am using [Jgrapht library](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht)

Comment: @AlexWien has the correct generic answer. Did you forget some detail in your question something related to the directed-acyclic-graphs tag perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple, just replace the undirected edge between two nodes A and B with two directed edges. One from A->B and the other from B -> A.